# Python multiprocessing - Is there a way to make sure python process stops after execution of the program

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Using pool with multi processing for hitting an api and storing the response into mysql for around 5k queries. The program never exits even after complete execution.Found that this happens as the processes are still open after execution.

Tried using join(), terminate(). Nothing works.

```
    def fetchAndStore(query):
        conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                 user=user,
                                 passwd=passwd,
                                 db=db)

        x = conn.cursor()
        full_url = getFullUrl(redirection_service, query)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
        html = response.read()
        data = json.loads(html)
        if data is not None:
             store =  json.dumps(data["RESPONSE"]["redirectionStore"])
        else:
             store = 'search.flipkart.com'
        try:
            stmt = "INSERT INTO golden_response(`store`) VALUES ('%s')" %( store)
            x.execute(stmt)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except Exception, e:
            global failure
            failure += 1
            print e
          return "Done"
   #main
   queries = db_connection()
   pool = Pool(processes=20, maxtasksperchild=5)
   results = []
   for query in queries:
       results.append(pool.apply_async(fetchAndStore, (query,)))

   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   print "completed"
```

The process should exit and print completed, in the ideal situation.

Comment: Have you tried closing the cursor and connection at the end?

Comment: I'm already doing that inside the function.Closing the connection every time.

Comment: You close it inside the try block, so when exception is raised the connection might not be closed. Try closing the connection and cursor inside finally block.

Comment: Makes sense. Tried that now. Still my process wouldn't exist. Had to force kill it .